# Tag for "hearing" or "audiometry"?

Tags: discussion, tags

What would be a fitting tag to use for questions about the "receiver" end of animal communication? Hearing seems straightforward, audiometry may be more descriptive but its more about the methodology, what do people think would be good?

Perhaps even just "receiver" would be useful.

Comment: I think 'receiver' is confusing-- a receiver can also be a hydrophone. I think there is room for both hearing AND audiometry (in my ignorant opinion), as audiometry is (I think) a subtopic of hearing related to measurement of hearing (?is it?)